# How to build a rich text view like Medium iOS app using Text Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, textkit

[image: Medium iOS App Screenshot]

It's a rich text view, with multiple images(variant height) among the text, and each of them sits between two paragraphs. Please refer to the screenshot.

I know that Text Kit supports exclusion paths, is it possible to build such a rich text view based on this technology? And how do you determine the position of the images when creating the exclusion paths?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an exclusion path because don't want to wrap the text around the image's shape. You just want the image to appear as its own centered paragraph. That means you need newlines (`\n`) before and after the image attachment, and you need to set a paragraph style with `alignment = .Center` on the attachment.

Example:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let richText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello!\n")
let attachment = NSTextAttachment(data: nil, ofType: nil)
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "Kaz-256.jpg")
let imageText = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
let imageStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
imageStyle.alignment = .Center
imageText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: imageStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, imageText.length))
richText.appendAttributedString(imageText)
richText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\nGoodbye."))


let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480))
textView.attributedText = richText
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = textView
```

Result:

[image: example result]

Comment: What about having a space between the text on top and the image, something like Medium´s iOS app editor?

Comment: Did you try adding more newlines before the image? Or you could set the `paragraphSpacingBefore` property of the `NSParagraphStyle` of the image.